# Matrix of a Linear Transformation — Equation for polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I'm reading a LinAlg book. With zero problems so far, until this example

Find a linear transformation $T: \mathbf{P}_{2} \rightarrow \mathbf{M}_{22}$ such that
$$
T(1+x)=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right], \quad T\left(x+x^{2}\right)=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right], \quad \text { and } \quad T\left(1+x^{2}\right)=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Solution. The set $\left\{1+x, x+x^{2}, 1+x^{2}\right\}$ is a basis of $\mathbf{P}_{2}$, so every vector $p=a+b x+c x^{2}$ in $\mathbf{P}_{2}$ is a linear combination of these vectors. In fact
$$
p(x)=\frac{1}{2}(a+b-c)(1+x)+\frac{1}{2}(-a+b+c)\left(x+x^{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}(a-b+c)\left(1+x^{2}\right)
$$
Hence Theorem 7.1.3 gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
T[p(x)] &=\frac{1}{2}(a+b-c)\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]+\frac{1}{2}(-a+b+c)\left[\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right]+\frac{1}{2}(a-b+c)\left[\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\begin{array}{rr}
a+b-c & -a+b+c \\
-a+b+c & a-b+c
\end{array}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

How do I get the polynomial equation involving the basis in an analytical way? What am I missing?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7cZR.jpg)

Comment: Please don't use pictures, they are not searchable etc.. Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

We know that a basis of $\mathbf{P}_{2}$ is  the set $\left\{1, x,x^{2}\right\}$ and note that  $\left\{1+ax+bx^2, c+x+dx^2,e+fx+x^2\right\}$  is a basis with $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are fixed  numbers in $\mathbb{R}$ the particular case you have $a=1,b=0,c=0,d=1,e=1,f=0.$